# How to change conda environments in custom image?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to use a preconfigured conda environment as my kernel in SageMaker Studio. I've gotten this working in the Terminal with a custom image. However, notebooks do not use the correct conda environment by default. Attempting to change environments results in conda errors.

```
!conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/ubuntu/miniconda
pipeline                 /home/ubuntu/miniconda/envs/pipeline
```

```
!conda activate pipeline

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

The container is set up to use the correct conda environment when using bash (through .bashrc, conda activate) so Terminal works properly.

What's the right approach to using a desired conda environment by default in a notebook?

Comment: Hey did you ever find an answer to if using environments is necessary? I'm moving from jupyter notebooks in sagemaker to Sagemaker studio and not been able to find this answer anywhere.

Comment: @warri0r_princess Using an environment isn't necessary, but you need to make sure you have the ipykernel installed whether it is in the virtual env or installed globally in the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To activate them on notebooks, use the Kernel Switcher. If you have `ipykernel` installed, you should be able to see the environments in the Kernel switcher. For a sample implementation on a DataScience image, see [this github repository](https://github.com/durgasury/efs_backed_conda).